# selenium count elements of xpath

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, web2py

i have a webpage with a table containing many Download links
i want to let selenium click on the last one :

table:

```
item1 Download
item2 Download
item3 Download
```

selenium must click on `Download` next `item3`

i used xpath to find all elments then get size of returned array or dict in this way

```
x = bot._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Download')]").size()
```

but i get always this error

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

i tried to use `get_xpath_count` methode but the methode doen't exist in selenium in python!

i thought about another solution but i don't know how to do it and it is as following

```
x = bot._driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Download')])[size()-1]")
```

or

```
x = bot._driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Download')])[last()]")
```

or something else

Comment: Can you print the result of `bot._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Download')]")`?

Comment: [size](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.size) is a property. If you want to find all items matching your `xpath` use `find_elements_by_xpath` (note the `s`).

Comment: @kroolik, yeah it works now with "s" but it returns an empty list, `size()` doesn't work but `len(x)` works. in another hand `bot._driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Download')])[5]").click()` ***without "s"*** works! so why does `find_elements_by_xpath` returns empty list :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to do this is to use JavaScript and find elements by class name

```
self.bot._driver.execute_script("var e = document.getElementsByClassName('download'); e[e.length-1].click()")
```

source: 
http://de.slideshare.net/adamchristian/javascript-testing-via-selenium

Answer (score 2):

Use find_elements_by_xpath to get number of relevant elements

```
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath))
```

Then click on the last element:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath[count])
elem.click()
```

Notice: the find_elements_by_xpath is plural in first code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Although `get_xpath_count("Xpath_Expression")` does not exist in Python, you can use

```
len(bot._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Download')]"))
```

to achieve the number of elements, and then iterate through then, using

```
something.xpath(//a[position()=n])
```

where

`n < len(bot._driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Download')]"))`

Comment: I use find_elements_by_xpath instead of find_element_by_xpath. The method have Plural.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this help me